# Cross join or subquery when one table is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have two tables 'property' and 'bookings'. I want to find out property for city, checkin and checkout when **bookings table is empty**.

when `bookings` table empty, for `city = 'bali' and checkin = '2020-07-20' and checkout = '2020-07-30'`, expected output is property id 1 and 2.

when `bookings` table not empty, for `city = 'bali' and checkin = '2020-07-20' and checkout = '2020-07-30'`, expected output is property id 1.

Query should work both when bookings table is empty / not empty.

property:

```
+----+---------+------+
| id |  city   | type |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | bali    |    1 |
|  2 | bali    |    1 |
|  3 | bangkok |    1 |
+----+---------+------+
```

bookings:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | property_id |  checkin   |  checkout  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 | 2020-07-18 | 2020-07-19 |
|  2 |           2 | 2020-07-20 | 2020-07-25 |
|  3 |           3 | 2020-07-20 | 2020-07-30 |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+
```

What will be best approach subquery or left join? I tried both approach but unable to get the expected result.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: JOIN. It uses indices with guarantee.

Comment: What output do you actually want to see in the case that `bookings` be empty?

Comment: for bookings empty, when city = 'bali' and checkin = '2020-07-20' and checkout = '2020-07-30' expected output is property id 1 and 2. 

for bookings not empty, when city = 'bali' and checkin = '2020-07-20' and checkout = '2020-07-30' expected output is property id 1.

Query should also work when bookings is not empty. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please for code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Strawberry suggested, I am able to make it work:

```
SELECT property.id FROM property 
LEFT JOIN bookings 
ON bookings.checkin < '2020-08-30' 
AND bookings.checkout > '2020-08-20' 
AND bookings.property_id = property.id 
WHERE city = 'bali'
AND bookings.id IS NULL
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense . It's equivalent to `WHERE 1 OR 1` - and never use `SELECT *`

Comment: do you have any better implementation, somehow this query is giving me expected result @Strawberry

Comment: Unfortunately, you've already accepted a flawed answer

Comment: I've removed the answer as accepted, would you please give me correct solution @Strawberry

Comment: I'm away from a pc right now; if nobody beats me to it, I'll send you a correct solution this evening, but essentially it's going to like `SELECT c.olumns, y.ou, a.ctually, w.ant FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON y.start < 'my_end_date AND y.end > my_start_date' AND y.stuff = x.stuff WHERE x.something = '?' AND y.id IS NULL`

Comment: You're welcome to write it up as an answer, and then accept that (when the system let's you - it's not like I need the points :-)   )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM property
LEFT JOIN bookings ON bookings.property_id = property.id
WHERE city='bali'
AND IF(bookings.id IS NULL, 1, bookings.checkin = '2020-07-18')
AND IF(bookings.id IS NULL, 1, bookings.checkout = '2020-07-19')
```

If there doesn't exists any record in the bookings table then simply apply the filter on the city only otherwise filter will be applied ont eh checkin and checkout as well.